# Timeout from navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is not triggering error callback

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have the following Javascript code, for getting user localization:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getStores, getStoresError, {
    'enableHighAccuracy' : true,
    'timeout' : 10000,
    'maximumAge' : 0
});
```

Both callbacks are being called when the user accepts or rejects the localization request. But if no answer is provided in 10 secs I was expecting timeout to expire and getStoresError to be called. This is not happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The timeout timer doesn’t start counting down until after the user gives permission to even try to calculate their position

```
 var options = {timeout:10000,enableHighAccuracy:true,maximumAge:0};

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getStores,getStoresError,options);
```

Comment: I still have the same result, as expected. I would be very surprise if that was the answer

Comment: The timeout option is outlined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions
This will start counting down once the user has given permission.

Comment: Ok. Now I get it. I thought timeout was the period of time given from the request until an answer from the user. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a global variable which is only updated on the success method for navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition. You can then create a setTimeout function lasting 10 secs which checks whether that value has been updated or not.

The only problem with this is that if the user clicks on Allow and your timeout expires just before the location is retrieved, you might be handling the response prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

After try a lot in dev environment. I finally found that from 2016 chrome has disable that api in unsecured environment, it has to be done from https, hope this would save people's time. See this link below, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only.